# How to customize Dropzone js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropzone.js

How do I customize Dropzone js? I searched for hours, but only gone in loops. I'm trying to go from this...[image]

To something like this...[image]

I don't need the background or any fancy styles, and the functionality already works. I Just mainly need the files to be like they are in the red box. But I don't know where to start.

Here is my main.js and css I used to style what you see in the first picture...

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

const myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone", {
    url: "upload/",
    maxFiles: 2,
    maxFilesize: 20,
    acceptedFiles: '.csv, .xlsx',
    preview_image: false,
    inputLabelWithFiles: false,
    // autoProcessQueue: false,
    // uploadMultiple: True,
    // previewTemplate: '',
})
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.dz {
    border: dashed !important;
    border-color: #ccc !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.dz:hover {
    background-color: aliceblue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I thought I needed to edit the dropzone's html, which I could not find. However, I realized I only needed css. After trying different things, this is now what it looks like...[image]
And here is the updated style.css...

```css
body {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.dz {
    margin-top: 180px;
    border: dashed !important;
    border-color: #ccc !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;

    /* REQUIRED. This will prevent the dropzone area from getting bigger.*/
    max-height: 150px !important;
}


/* Here are the other styles for Dropzone. 
These will give it the same look as in the
picture. Which I think is better for non image files.*/

/* Manually place the uploaded files.*/
.dropzone .dz-preview {
    top: 200px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    min-height: 0px !important;
}

/* Manually create the shape of the bubble.*/
.dz-image {
    width: 1000px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    /* Add this to create cool colors, if you want. */
    /* background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #28a745, #dc3545) !important; */
    position: relative;
}

/* Manually put the file size into the bubble. */
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details > .dz-size {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px !important;
}

/* Manually put the file name into the bubble.*/
.dz-details > .dz-filename {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px !important;
    left: 100px !important;
}

/* Put the details below the upload area and button. */
.dz-details {
    position: absolute;
    top: 305.5px;
}

/* Make the loading bar slim and cover 80% of the file bubble.*/
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress {
    position: relative !important;
    height: 6px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    width: 80% !important;
    margin-left: 97px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}

/* Haven't changed the checkbox that comes after the loading bar.*/
```

You could also implement these into the dropzone.css file, if you downloaded that. I already did it...

```css
/*
 * The MIT License
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Matias Meno <m@tias.me>
 */
@-webkit-keyframes passing-through {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
    -o-transform: translateY(40px);
    transform: translateY(40px); }
  30%, 70% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px); }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
    transform: translateY(-40px); } }
@-moz-keyframes passing-through {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
    -o-transform: translateY(40px);
    transform: translateY(40px); }
  30%, 70% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px); }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
    transform: translateY(-40px); } }
@keyframes passing-through {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
    -o-transform: translateY(40px);
    transform: translateY(40px); }
  30%, 70% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px); }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
    transform: translateY(-40px); } }
@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
    -o-transform: translateY(40px);
    transform: translateY(40px); }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px); } }
@-moz-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
    -o-transform: translateY(40px);
    transform: translateY(40px); }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px); } }
@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
    -o-transform: translateY(40px);
    transform: translateY(40px); }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px); } }
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1); }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1); }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1); } }
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1); }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1); }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1); } }
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1); }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1); }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1); } }
.dropzone, .dropzone * {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.dropzone {
  margin-top: 180px;
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: white;
  padding: 20px 20px; }
  .dropzone.dz-clickable {
    cursor: pointer; }
    .dropzone.dz-clickable * {
      cursor: default; }
    .dropzone.dz-clickable .dz-message, .dropzone.dz-clickable .dz-message * {
      cursor: pointer; }
  .dropzone.dz-started .dz-message {
    display: none; }
  .dropzone.dz-drag-hover {
    border-style: solid; }
    .dropzone.dz-drag-hover .dz-message {
      opacity: 0.5; }
  .dropzone .dz-message {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2em 0; }
    .dropzone .dz-message .dz-button {
      background: none;
      color: inherit;
      border: none;
      padding: 0;
      font: inherit;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: inherit; }
  .dropzone .dz-preview {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    top: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    min-height: 0px; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview:hover {
      z-index: 1000; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview:hover .dz-details {
        opacity: 1; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview .dz-image {
      border-radius: 20px;
      background: #999;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee, #ddd); }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview .dz-details {
      opacity: 1; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-image-preview {
      background: white; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-image-preview .dz-details {
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        transition: opacity 0.2s linear; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-remove {
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: none; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-remove:hover {
        text-decoration: underline; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview:hover .dz-details {
      opacity: 1; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details {
      z-index: 20;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      font-size: 13px;
      min-width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      padding: 2em 1em;
      text-align: center;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
      line-height: 150%; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-size {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        font-size: 16px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename {
        color: #000000;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 100px;
        white-space: nowrap; }
        .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename:hover span {
          border: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
          background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); }
        .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename:not(:hover) {
          overflow: hidden;
          text-overflow: ellipsis; }
          .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename:not(:hover) span {
            border: 1px solid transparent; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename span, .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-size span {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
        padding: 0 0.4em;
        border-radius: 3px; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview:hover .dz-image img {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
      -o-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
      transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
      -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
      filter: blur(8px); }
    .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-image {
      border-radius: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 20px;
      /* Maybe try 'fixed' if something goes wrong. */
      position: relative;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #28a745, #dc3545);
      display: block;
      z-index: 10; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-image img {
        display: block; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-success .dz-success-mark {
      -webkit-animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      -moz-animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      -ms-animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      -o-animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1); }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-error .dz-error-mark {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      -moz-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      -ms-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      -o-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1); }
    .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-success-mark, .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-mark {
      pointer-events: none;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 500;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -27px;
      margin-top: -27px; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-success-mark svg, .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-mark svg {
        display: block;
        width: 54px;
        height: 54px; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-processing .dz-progress {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
      -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
      -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
      -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
      transition: all 0.2s linear; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-complete .dz-progress {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
      transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview:not(.dz-processing) .dz-progress {
      -webkit-animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
      -moz-animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
      -ms-animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
      -o-animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
      animation: pulse 6s ease infinite; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress {
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 1000;
      pointer-events: none;
      position: relative;
      height: 6px;
      /* left: 50%; */
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -8px;
      width: 80%;
      margin-left: 97px;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      /* border-radius: 8px; */
      overflow: hidden; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress .dz-upload {
        background: #333;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #661, #444);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 0;
        -webkit-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
        transition: width 300ms ease-in-out; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-error .dz-error-message {
      display: block; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-error:hover .dz-error-message {
      opacity: 1;
      pointer-events: auto; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-message {
      pointer-events: none;
      z-index: 1000;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      display: none;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
      transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
      border-radius: 8px;
      font-size: 13px;
      top: 130px;
      left: -10px;
      width: 140px;
      background: #be2626;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #be2626, #a92222);
      padding: 0.5em 1.2em;
      color: white; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-message:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -6px;
        left: 64px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 6px solid transparent;
        border-right: 6px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 6px solid #be2626; }
```

Just copy all that and swap out your existing dropzone.css file if you want this same look.
Anyway hopes this helps anyone else who wants to use dropzone with this type of style. Which I think is very idea of any non image files. No html javascript or anything else. Just pure css.

Answer (score 2):

You could check this [article](https://onyxdev.net/snippets-item/dropzonejs-example-with-translations-custom-preview-and-upload-delete-file-with-php/)

```
 new Dropzone(target, {
        ... 
        previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
        previewsContainer: "#previews",
```

Also, in the [documentation](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-previewsContainer)

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it, every time I downloaded a file I called ajax function, which first added css (display: none), for emements in dropzone, and then called php script. It was responsible for displaying all files that were saved to previously empty div (div was under dropzone).